# Lifetime of an object that is supplied as a value to CFReadStreamSetProperty()

Tags: c, core-foundation, cfnetwork

I need to supply value of type `CFNumberRef` to `CFReadStreamSetProperty()`. I am working with  `CFReadStream` that is returned by `CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest()`. Should I call `CFRelease()` over my `CFNumberRef`, or do I have to preserve `CFNumberRef` till `CFReadStream` exists?

My code looks like:

```
void func(..., const long long id)
{
    //...
    CFReadStreamRef httpReadStream =  CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest(...);
    //...
    CFNumberRef cf_id = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberLongLongType,
                                       &id);
    CFReadStreamSetProperty(httpReadStream, CFSTR("myId"), cf_id);
}
```

So should I call `CFRelease(cf_id)` and does it matter if `cf_id` is released before `httpReadStream`?

Answer (score 0):

OK, according to: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html, it seems that I should call `CFRelease()`, because as it says:

*A corollary of the basic rules is that when you pass an object to another object (as a function parameter), you should expect that the receiver will take ownership of the passed object if it needs to maintain it.*

So `CFReadStreamSetProperty()` should call `CFRetain()` if it wants to use my object in the future.